# Does the fantasy world in Joe the Barbarian exist outside of Joe's perspective?

Tags: vertigo-comics, joe-the-barbarian

*[Joe the Barbarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_the_Barbarian)* is a Vertigo miniseries by Grant Morrison. It appears that the fantasy world Joe switches back and forth between is actually him having hallucinations in the real world as he is going through hypoglycemia (for instance, a waterfall that appears in the fantasy world is really an overflowing water faucet he left on). By the end,

> Joe is convinced that the fantasy world will end once he drinks a soda to get his blood sugar back up, and that appears to be what happens in the comic.

However, there are a number of scenes that take place outside of Joe's perspective, notably the monks watching Joe in the real world on a TV. That seems to suggest that the fantasy world exists independently of Joe.

So does the fantasy world exist outside of Joe's perspective? Is it "real" in that it continues to exist even if Joe is not hallucinating?

<sub>A lot of writers pushing the "was it a dream or was it real?" question tend to ignore the fact that things happen outside of the individual's perspective. Heck, even *The Wizard of Oz* film does that with scenes of the Wicked Witch. I don't know if it's lazy writing or lack of attention to detail, so I'm not sure it's definitive proof in this case.</sub>